# Alternative to String.equals for multiple compares (without enum)

Tags: java, string, reflection, equals, switch-statement

I have thought about making enums for all my fields, but that doesn't look to cool either (i have many classes that implements similar methods). Is there a better way?

```
public void writeAttribute(String attribute, Object value) {
    if (attribute.equals("title")) {
        title = (String) value;
    } else if (attribute.equals("description")) {
        description = (String) value;
    } else if (attribute.equals("room")) {
        room = (Room) value;
    } else if (attribute.equals("type")) {
        type = AppointmentType.valueOf((String) value);
    } else if (attribute.equals("guestCount")) {
        guestCount = (Integer) value;
    }
}
```

Depending on the `attribute` parameter, i want to map the input `value` to the appropriate field. Is there a way to clean up/optimize my code? Writing `.equals` for every field isn't too elegant.

Comment: if `attribute` is null, `NullPointerException`. :)

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this would be to avoid casts entirely, and use polymorphism or method overloading. Perhaps you could provide a little more background about what you're trying to implement. It sounds like serialization, in which case there are plenty of really good libraries out there that can do all this nasty stuff for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java SE 7 (July 28, 2011) you **can** switch strings.

Comment: You answered (and approved) your own question?  Also, the purist in me is not convinced that allowing switch on String is all that great an idea in the long run - it just makes it "easier" to avoid doing it the "right" way which is polymorphism.  The pragmatic in me is o.k. with a switch, if used in moderation.

Comment: @user949300 [It's OK to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than have an individual named member variable for each attribute, have you considered using a HashMap to store attributes? Your class would have an attribute map

```
Map<String,Object> attributes = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

and your method above reduces to

```
public void writeAttribute(String attribute, Object value) {
    this.attributes.put(attribute,value);
}
```

Since you're casting anyway, you would then have methods that cast the value appropriately when you access it, or cast it yourself at the point of access.

Comment: I have considered it, but that isn't very The Java Way? This method is only for serialization/deserialization part, but/so I want the rest of the class to be as "normal"/conventional

Comment: Well, the "Java Way" would be to have individual getters and setters, which you aren't doing either.  I vote for either individual getters/setters, or use a Map as @Jim Garrison suggested.  You are in a weird middleground.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your attribute/value pairs in a map:

```
public void writeAttribute(String attribute, Object value) {
   attributeMap.put(attribute, value);
}
```

And then mapping them to fields is a little cleaner:

```
title = (String)map.get(value);
description = (String)map.get(value);
room = (Room)map.get(value);
type = AppointmentType.valueOf((String)map.get(value));
guestCount = (Integer)map.get(value);
```

Comment: Interesting. But I also want it to update partially -- only a few attributes, so there is no guarantee that the `key` will be in the map. Then i would have to check if the map `.containsKey` for every attribute, and I'm back to square one :/

Comment: In the case of an update, you could pre-fill the map with the current attributes, overwrite any that have changed, and then anything that is still null is legitimately so, no?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this: (feel free to use interface other than Runnable)

```
interface AttributeEvaluator {
  Object getValue(String s);
}

enum Attribute {
  TITLE(new AttributeEvaluator() { public Object getValue(String str) { return (String)value; }),
  ROOM(new AttributeEvaluator() { public Object getValue(String str) { return (Room)value; });


  private Attribute(AttributeEvaluator r) {
    this.evaluator = evaluator;
  }

  public <T> T getValueOf(String str) {
    return (T)evaluator.getValue(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your code doesn't compile and contains some mistakes. Maybe you should review it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if your method is OK to avoid such if-conditions, try do something like that:

```
public void writeAttributes(Map<String, Object> attributesMap) {
    title = (String) attributesMap.get(TITLE);
    description = (String) attributesMap.get(DESCRIPTION);
    ...
}
```

where TITLE and DESCRIPTION is your final variables. If you won't have value in your Map for example in description then you'll have there null.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using reflection, check out this [post](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) which explains how to get a field and then set the value for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public void writeAttribute(String attribute, Object value) {
    Field field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField(attribute);
    field.setAccesible(true);
    field.set(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We write preprocessed Java, for which you can find the [processing code](https://vexi.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/vexi/trunk/org.vexi-build.jpp/) here.

It gives us **string switches**.  However it adds an additional step to compilation.  Files that require processing are named `Foo.jpp` and are processed to `Foo.java`, but the pervasiveness of `String`-based switches in our code more than makes up for this inconvenience.

Example:

```
/** set flags on added traps */
public void addTrap(JS key, JS function) throws JSExn {
    super.addTrap(key, function);
    // differentiate between read and write traps
    if (function.getFormalArgs().length != 1) {
        //#switch (JSU.toString(key))
        case "surface": set(SURFACE_READ_TRAP);
        case "visible": set(VISIBLE_READ_TRAP);
        case "Children": set(CHILDREN_READ_TRAP);
        //#end
        return;
    }
    //#switch (JSU.toString(key))
    case "x":         set(X_TRAP);
    case "y":         set(Y_TRAP);
    case "width":     set(WIDTH_TRAP);
    case "height":    set(HEIGHT_TRAP);
    case "minwidth":  set(MINWIDTH_TRAP);
    case "maxwidth":  set(MAXWIDTH_TRAP);
    case "minheight": set(MINHEIGHT_TRAP);
    case "maxheight": set(MAXHEIGHT_TRAP);
    case "contentwidth": set(CONTENTWIDTH_TRAP);
    case "contentheight": set(CONTENTHEIGHT_TRAP);
    case "surface":   set(SURFACE_TRAP); 
    case "visible":   set(VISIBLE_TRAP);
    case "Children":  set(CHILDREN_TRAP);
    case "Enter":     set(ENTER_TRAP);
    case "Leave":     set(LEAVE_TRAP);
    case "_Move":     set(_MOVE_TRAP);
    case "Move":      set(MOVE_TRAP);
    case "fontsize":  renderprops.setTrapFontsize(this);
    case "font":      renderprops.setTrapFont(this);
    case "shrink":    set(SHRINK_TRAP);
    case "hshrink":   set(HSHRINK_TRAP);
    case "vshrink":   set(VSHRINK_TRAP);
    //#end
}
```